# RShiny leaflet don't want to connect polylines

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I have a dataset like so:

OriginLong | OriginLat | DestLong | DestLat

And I want to draw lines from origin to destination, which is proving more difficult than I expected. I am filtering the data by different cuts, so there will be a variable number of rows. Initially I stacked the datasets so it was like:

```
Departs <- reactive({

  data <- pipedataout()[,3:4]
  colnames(data) <- c("Latitude","Longitude")
  data$seq <- c(sequence = seq(1, length.out = nrow(data), by=2))
  data2 <- pipedataout()[,7:8]
  colnames(data2) <- c("Latitude","Longitude")
  data2$seq <- c(sequence = seq(2, length.out = nrow(data2), by=2))
  data <- sqldf("SELECT * FROM data
                UNION ALL
                SELECT * FROM data2
                ORDER BY seq")
  print(data)
  data
})
```

Header : Long | Lat
Row 1: OrgLon1 | orgLat1
Row 2: DestLon1 | DestLat1
Row 3: OrgLon2 | orgLat2
Row 4: DestLon3 | DestLat3

But it draws a line from row 1 to row 2, row 2 to row 3, row 3 to row 4, etc. So I get a lot of lines I don't want. How can I draw a line from row 1 to row 2, row 3 to row 4, row 5 to row 6, or Row 1 Origin -> Destination, row 2 origin to destination, etc. I thought this would be a pretty common question but I haven't found a good answer! I tried looping it and drawing each line individually but that seems like an inefficient route.

Thanks

Comment: Couldn't find a good solution to this, so instead of lines I put periods every so often between the two locations. Had them increasing in size to denote flow direction.